# layout conrols to developp universal apps in windows 8.1 pro

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am new in universal Windows Platform but I have a problem with my UWP project,when I select new Project -> Visual C# ->Windows ->Universal I didn't get any controls in layout (MainPage.xaml) and when I choose view Design I get nothing but When I choose Visual C# ->Windows >windows 8 ->Universal I can use the controls in "my MainPage.xaml"(a shared and a windows phone project are created)

I have repaired the visual studio 2015 and I have installed the universal tools but I still get this problem,I work with a windows 8.1 professional 64 bits OS

have you please any idea about the problem and how can I solve it
thanks a lot for help

Comment: Which project template are you using? Blank App?

Comment: yes Bells I use Blank App and sorry for late :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to install Windows 10. Even though documentation says you can develop UWP on windows 8.1, you won't be able even to test it on windows 8.1 PC. You'll need physical remote PC with windows 10 to test your app. You can't deploy windows 10 app on windows 8.1 PC since they have different API.

Limitation from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx):

> You can only use the XAML designer if your development platform is
>   Windows 10.